# SugarORM query from multiple tables?

Tags: android, sqlite, sugarorm, multi-table

I am using SugarORM for my Android application. In my project I have couple of tables and I was wondering is there a way to to join them into another Class Object that has columns from multiple tables?

If yes, then example would be very helpful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SugarORM provides a Query Builder object for simple queries. Since it doesn't provide supporto for joins, you can directly execute a **raw query** and store the result into an object created ad-hoc.

So, build your custom raw query renaming the fields in the SELECT part

```
CustomOBJ.executeQuery("SELECT tableA.fieldA as field1, tableA.fieldB as field2, tableB.fieldA as field 3 FROM tableA JOIN tableB WHERE .....");
```

and then create your custom object

```
public CustomOBJ {
    private String field1;
    private String field2;  
    private String field3;

   public CustomOBJ(){} //you must declare an empty constructor

   //getters
   //setters
}
```

Here the documentation:

- [raw queries with joins in sqlite](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_using_joins.htm)
- [how to execute queries in sugarORM](http://satyan.github.io/sugar/query.html)

Comment: If you're using a `SELECT` query, you should use the `findWithQuery` method, as it returns a list, opposed to `executeQuery`, which is `void`. (Using SugarORM v1.5)

Comment: So, following the answer, it should be `CustomOBJ.findWithQuery(CustomOBJ.class, "SELECT ...", ...)` - replace and data with your own.     (And as a sidenote, you can use `SugarRecord.findWithQuery` if it feels less weird than repeating the object).

Comment: Thanks for the link!  It helped me.