# Retrieving data from Json array which is stored in a table in the sugerorm database. Android Ask

Tags: java, android, arrays, object, sugarorm

i have model class product which has all the fields of product json and i have another table called tag which consist string type variable called tag. Id of tag is passed as an array to the product json field called tag as mentioned above. I have a helper class called producttag to have the reference of product and tag. to maintain  many to many relationship in sugerorm database. i was able to add the data to the database successfully. can some one help me retrieve product for the matching tag. how do i implement that?

above is the Json i've created. In the database i store values for the product in a product table. theres another table which consist a column called tag. how do i find matching product for given tag.

Comment: Share codes it will help the people who are trying to give you a solution

Comment: {
   "tag": "Accessories"
  },
  {
    "tag": "Xl"

Comment: Answer is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35534733/sugarorm-query-from-multiple-tables

Comment: provide more detail, your question is not clear. :)

Comment: i have updated my question. can you suggest a way i can retrieve the data for the above senario. @AmirDe

Comment: Post your codes not the json format

Comment: @IndraKumarS i've shown above the adding part to the database. The question was edited. How do i get the product for a matching tag. As u can see its two tables whch has many to many relationship.

Comment: @IndraKumarS  can u help me doing this.